# R aggregate columns based on a factor column's value and create a new data frame

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I have following R data table:

```
> head(dt)
      X0   X1   X2  X3   X4  X5 X6 X7  X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 grp
1: 33653 2325  916 720  867 187 31  0   6  3  42  56  92  15  69   0 a-4
2: 18895  414 1116 570 1190  55 92  0 122 23  78   6   4   2  11   0 a-3
3:  1383   70   27  17   17   1  0  0   0  0   1   0   0   0   3   0 a-6
4:   396   72   34   5   18   0  0  0   0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0 a-5
5:  3915 1170  402 832 2791 316 12  5 118 51  32   9  62  27   1   0 a-3
6:   554   33  138  13  415   4  5  0   0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0 a-5
```

I want to create a new data frame that has column wise aggregation respect to value in the `grp` column. Based on above 6 records `row2`, and `row5` should be sum together as well as `row4` and `row6`, and new data table now have 4 rows instead of 6.

I tried to use `ddply` as follows:

```
> ddply(dt, numcolwise(sum))
```

but ended up getting following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Comment: You haven't specified a grouping column in the `ddply` code.

Comment: Why would you use `plyr::ddply` on a `data.table`?

Comment: @Arun new to data table - Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
options(stringsAsFactors=F)
##
dt <- data.table(
  matrix(rep(1,96),ncol=16))
dt[,grp:=c(
  "a-4","a-3","a-6",
  "a-5","a-3","a-5")]
##
> dt[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=grp]
   grp V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16
1: a-4  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2: a-3  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
3: a-6  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
4: a-5  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
```

**Edit**
Here's how I would try to visualize the data. I'm going to use a slightly different set of data - same structure, different numbers:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
options(stringsAsFactors=F)
##
dt <- data.table(
  matrix(1:96,ncol=16))
dt[,grp:=c(
  "a-4","a-3","a-6",
  "a-5","a-3","a-5")]
##
gt <- dt[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=grp]
> gt
   grp V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16
1: a-4  1  7 13 19 25 31 37 43  49  55  61  67  73  79  85  91
2: a-3  7 19 31 43 55 67 79 91 103 115 127 139 151 163 175 187
3: a-6  3  9 15 21 27 33 39 45  51  57  63  69  75  81  87  93
4: a-5 10 22 34 46 58 70 82 94 106 118 130 142 154 166 178 190
```

Start by reshaping the `data.table` from *wide* format to *long* format:

```
gt_long <- reshape(
  gt,
  direction="long",
  varying=list(names(gt)[-1]),
  v.names="Value",
  idvar="grp",
  timevar="V_ID",
  times=paste0("V",1:16))
> head(gt_long)
   grp V_ID Value
1: a-4   V1     1
2: a-3   V1     7
3: a-6   V1     3
4: a-5   V1    10
5: a-4   V2     7
6: a-3   V2    19
```

Then you can treat the `Vi`s as factor variables, and you have some options with `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(
  data=gt_long,
  aes(x=V_ID,y=Value,color=grp))+
  geom_point(size=5,alpha=.75)+
  scale_colour_brewer(type="div",palette=4)
```

[image]

Or, if that is too cluttered for you:

```
ggplot(
  data=gt_long,
  aes(x=V_ID,y=Value,color=grp))+
  geom_point(size=4)+
  facet_grid(grp ~ .)
```

[image]

**Edit 2** 
There might be a slightly more concise way to order the levels correctly, but this works. I made a copy of the `gt_long` object just so I could check that it worked without modifying the original, but you can just use the original object.

```
gt_long2 <- copy(gt_long)
v_levels <- unique(gt_long2$V_ID)
gt_long2[,V_ID:=factor(
  V_ID,
  levels=v_levels,
  labels=v_levels)]
```

I'm not going to add the plots, but I reran them with `gt_long2` and it looked good.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Do you have any recommendation on how to visualize this? There are only 5 grps.

Comment: Possibly - how are you trying to visualize it? Do the column names `V1:V16` hold particular significance - i.e. is it important to compare values of `V1` to other values of `V1`, `V2` to other values of `V2`, etc... across `grp`, essentially treating each `Vi` like a factor? Or do all `Vi`s constitute a set of values for each `grp`, where the order / particular column name isn't important - i.e. just the distribution of values by `grp`?

Comment: Yes, there is a significant. As you said comparing to a-4 V1 with a-3 V1 is important. Column order is not important as its position but values in column is important respect to grp.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis Okay, I added a couple of options to get you started.

Comment: I started like this `dt.molten <- melt(dt.aggregate, value.name="count", variable.name="X_Val", na.rm=TRUE)` but I like your approach, is there away to keep the order of X axis, like `V1, V2, V3` instead of `V1, V10` Thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want sum of the rows as per the grp variable then below code will work, have taken x0 and x1 just for ex. purpose.

```
s<- ddply(dt, c("grp"), summarise,New_x0=sum(x0),New_x1=sum(x1))
```